# Is there a way to expand the code window in VS.NET to maximum size?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Eclipse you can double-click on the tab of the code window and expand it to full size, e.g. if you will be working on just the code awhile and want maximum size on a smaller monitor, etc.

Is there a way to expand the code window in Visual Studio.NET in one click (otherwise I have to collapse Toolbox, Solution Explorer, Properties, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shift+Alt+Enter takes you to full screen mode, which hides most panes. The only two I had were a close window history and my pending check-ins, but for the most part this works well.

Comment: If you want a way to do this with the mouse, you'll need to customize the toolbar or menu to provide a command that executes the same functionality as the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's on the view menu for me by default in VS2008